# Alfresco Share - Search not working for non-Administrator users

Tags: java, search, share, alfresco, access-denied

I'm confused as to why I can search as an Administrator but users cannot. Please see the following error stack generated when attempting to search as a normal user.

```
05:57:00,784  ERROR [extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime] Exception from executeScript - redirecting to status template error: 08210015 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 08210835 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js': 08210834 Access Denied.  You do not have the appropriate permissions to perform this operation.
org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException: 08210015 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 08210835 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js': 08210834 Access Denied.  You do not have the appropriate permissions to perform this operation.
at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.createStatusException(AbstractWebScript.java:758)
at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:171)
at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer$2.execute(RepositoryContainer.java:377)
at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:381)
at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:436)
at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:466)
at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:304)
at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:333)
at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:189)
at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:118)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:58)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.alfresco.scripts.ScriptException: 08210835 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js': 08210834 Access Denied.  You do not have the appropriate permissions to perform this operation.
at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.execute(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:194)
at org.alfresco.repo.processor.ScriptServiceImpl.executeScript(ScriptServiceImpl.java:282)
at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryScriptProcessor.executeScript(RepositoryScriptProcessor.java:102)
at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.executeScript(AbstractWebScript.java:981)
at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:86)
... 24 more
Caused by: org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.AccessDeniedException: 08210834 Access Denied.  You do not have the appropriate permissions to perform this operation.
at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.java:48)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.proceedWithAudit(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:217)
at org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.proceed(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:184)
at org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:137)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:107)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy53.getAllSetPermissions(Unknown Source)
at org.alfresco.repo.site.SiteServiceImpl.getSiteVisibility(SiteServiceImpl.java:852)
at org.alfresco.repo.site.SiteServiceImpl.createSiteInfo(SiteServiceImpl.java:823)
at org.alfresco.repo.site.SiteServiceImpl.getSiteImpl(SiteServiceImpl.java:913)
at org.alfresco.repo.site.SiteServiceImpl.getSite(SiteServiceImpl.java:894)
at org.alfresco.repo.site.script.ScriptSiteService.getSite(ScriptSiteService.java:184)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor532.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:155)
at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:243)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:66)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c7._c1(file:/opt/alfresco/alfresco-3.4.d/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js:38)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c7.call(file:/opt/alfresco/alfresco-3.4.d/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:97)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c7._c6(file:/opt/alfresco/alfresco-3.4.d/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js:175)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c7.call(file:/opt/alfresco/alfresco-3.4.d/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:97)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c7._c13(file:/opt/alfresco/alfresco-3.4.d/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js:512)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c7.call(file:/opt/alfresco/alfresco-3.4.d/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:97)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c7._c15(file:/opt/alfresco/alfresco-3.4.d/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js:597)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c7.call(file:/opt/alfresco/alfresco-3.4.d/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:97)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c7._c16(file:/opt/alfresco/alfresco-3.4.d/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js:812)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c7.call(file:/opt/alfresco/alfresco-3.4.d/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:97)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c7._c17(file:/opt/alfresco/alfresco-3.4.d/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js:827)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c7.call(file:/opt/alfresco/alfresco-3.4.d/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName0(OptRuntime.java:108)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c7._c0(file:/opt/alfresco/alfresco-3.4.d/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js:830)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c7.call(file:/opt/alfresco/alfresco-3.4.d/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:393)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2834)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c7.call(file:/opt/alfresco/alfresco-3.4.d/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c7.exec(file:/opt/alfresco/alfresco-3.4.d/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js)
at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.executeScriptImpl(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:472)
at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.execute(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:190)
... 28 more
Caused by: net.sf.acegisecurity.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied.
at net.sf.acegisecurity.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:86)
at net.sf.acegisecurity.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:394)
at net.sf.acegisecurity.intercept.method.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:77)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.java:44)
... 74 more
```

Has anyone seen this before? Can anyone suggest where I might start looking?

Comment: What version of Alfresco are you using?

Comment: And also, what's the search you're trying to run that fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify a lot about your setup and what you did in Share before this error occurred so this is my educated guess from the stacktrace:

- You perform a site specific search, i.e. the search.js webscript is called with a siteId.
- From the webscript the SiteService is called:
  at org.alfresco.repo.site.SiteServiceImpl.getSite(SiteServiceImpl.java:894)
- The SiteServices tries to read the permissions for the site, when the error occurs:
  at $Proxy53.getAllSetPermissions

Is it possible that this is a private site and the user that is running the query has no permissions to access the site? Make sure the users are at least consumers in the site. You could also test if this occurs with public sites as well, or only with private ones.

Comment: Thanks for your response and apologies for not being verbose. I usually post to forums with the 'throw everything at the wall and see what sticks' approach, but I've found I get a more expert response if I don't - sad I know. Regardless, I think I know what this was. I think the ACLs got baulked during a backup and recreating them fixed searching. Thanks again for your input.